# Vertical alignment of p multirow in tabu

Tags: tables, tabu

I'm using `tabu` to create my tables. In one of the tables, I would like to have a `multirow` row and vertically align its content to top.

```
-------------- ---------------------------------
This is p col  First row
               ---------------------------------
               Second row
               ---------------------------------
               Third row
-------------- ---------------------------------
This is p col  First row
               ---------------------------------
               Second row
-------------- ---------------------------------
```

This is the basic latex code

```
\begin{table}
\tabulinesep =_3pt^3pt
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth{p{4cm} X}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{4cm}{This is p col} & First row \\
& Second row \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
```

I found several solutions to vertically align a `X` column, but not a `p` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,multirow,booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
\tabulinesep =_3pt^3pt
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth{p{4cm} X}
\toprule
\multirow{2}[-4]{4cm}{This is p col} & First row \\
& Second row \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]